# Deleting visible rows in autofilter - skipping empty filter results

Tags: excel, vba, rows, delete-row, autofilter

I currently have a macro going through multiple criteria in autofilter and deleting the visible rows.
This seems to work well, until there are no rows fitting the criteria and it gives me an error.

I've tried using the 'if' function below, but it doesn't seem to skip to 'End If' even there are no results under the autofilter, and LstRw would be 1.

Is there something wrong I've done with 'if' function, or is it the way I've used 'LstRw' (Range)?

```
With S1
    LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("$A$1:$G" & LstRw).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<" & Format(DatePast, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    .Range("$A$1:$G" & LstRw).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("ZD", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    If LstRw > 1 Then
        Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & LstRw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        rng.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    .ShowAllData
End With
```

Comment: I prefer Tim William's [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33264772/9245853) in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Why did you hide my question? you could've just commented with the link which doesn't answer my question by the way.  Can you open it again?

Comment: How does it not answer your question? Don't use `LstRw` like that, it won't work. Use the approach in the linked duplicate. When there are no cells fitting the criteria, then `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` will throw an error. That linked answer shows you exactly how to handle it. You just have to change the `.Copy` to `.EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: Thanks for providing more context and explanation, that's what I needed.