# If cell value in table range equals "New" copy entire row and paste as values in sheet 1 in the next empty cell

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, copy, copy-paste

I am trying to do a basic thing but cannot get it right.

I want to evaluate the cells on sheet 2(New Roster) in a table column(OldNew) for the value "New". If it has the value, copy the entire row and add it to the table(CurrentRoster) on sheet 1(Current Roster).

Here is the code I am using:

```
For Each c In wb.Names("OldNew").RefersToRange.Cells
    If c.Value Like "New" Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set SourceTable = Worksheets("New Roster").ListObjects("NewRoster").DataBodyRange
        Set DestinationTable = Worksheets("Current Roster").ListObjects("CurrentRoster").ListRows.Add
        SourceTable.Copy
        DestinationTable.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next
```

This endlessly loops and does not do what I want.

Here is the entire code for context:

```
Sub TableData()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim RangeName As String
    Dim CellName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, c As Range, m
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim SourceTable
    Dim DestinationTable

    Worksheets("New Roster").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    
    If Range("A1") = "" Then
         MsgBox "No Data to Reconcile"
         Exit Sub
        Else
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  '---->Prevents screen flickering as the code executes.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False  '---->Prevents warning "pop-ups" from appearing.
    
     ' Clears hidden columns from previous user
    Worksheets("Current Roster").Activate
    Range("A1").Activate
    Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Sheet1.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Tables the New Roster
    Worksheets("New Roster").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes).Name _
    = "NewRoster"
    Range("NewRoster[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("NewRoster").TableStyle = ""
    
    ' Name Ranges for Reference, New Name List From New Roster
    ActiveSheet.Range("F2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="NewNameList", RefersToR1C1:= _
    "=NewRoster[Member AHCCCS ID]"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("NewNameList").Comment = "Contains New list to compare old list to"

    
    ' Compares CurrentNameList Values to NewNameList Values to verify if current names are still active
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    For Each c In wb.Names("CurrentNameList").RefersToRange.Cells
        m = Application.Match(c.Value, wb.Names("NewNameList").RefersToRange, 0)
        c.Offset(0, 26).Value = IIf(IsError(m), "InActive", "Active")
    Next c

    ' Adds Column to New Roster Table and place Old/New in header cell
    Worksheets("New Roster").Activate
    Worksheets("New Roster").Range("AF1").Value = "Old/New"

    ' Names Old/New Range
    ActiveSheet.Range("AF1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="OldNew", RefersToR1C1:= _
    "=NewRoster[Old/New]"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("OldNew").Comment = ""

    ' Compares CurrentNameList Values to NewNameList Values to determine if New Name, If so, Add to Current 
    Roster
    For Each c In wb.Names("NewNameList").RefersToRange.Cells
        m = Application.Match(c.Value, wb.Names("CurrentNameList").RefersToRange, 0)
        c.Offset(0, 26).Value = IIf(IsError(m), "New", "Old")
    Next c
        
    ' Move Rows with "New" from New Roster to Current Roster Worksheet
    Worksheets("New Roster").Activate

    For Each c In wb.Names("OldNew").RefersToRange.Cells
        If c.Value Like "New" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Set SourceTable = Worksheets("New Roster").ListObjects("NewRoster").DataBodyRange
            Set DestinationTable = Worksheets("Current Roster").ListObjects("CurrentRoster").ListRows.Add
            SourceTable.Copy
            DestinationTable.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next
        
     ' Clear New Roster Data
    Worksheets("New Roster").Activate
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("NewNameList").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("OldNew").Delete
    Worksheets("Current Roster").Activate
    Range("A1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("CurrentRoster[#All]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, _
    3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
    30, 31 _
    , 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55), _
    Header:=xlYes



    Application.DisplayAlerts = True   '---->Resets the default.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True  '---->Resets the default.


End Sub
```

Comment: It may be easier to use `Range.AutoFilter`.

Comment: How do I account for the value not being found? No "New"...

Comment: [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259296/handle-no-cells-were-found-error-when-filtered-range-is-empty)?

Answer (score 1):

### Copy From Table to Table

- Remove the duplicate declarations and references.
- This will only work if both tables have the same number of columns and table `NewRoster` has a column with the header `OldNew`.
- It's a standalone version, so you can test it as is. Later you just have to delete the added rows.
- If you want to allow case-insensitivity (allow new,NEW), you can add `vbTextCompare` as the fourth argument in the `Instr` function.
- Forget about `On Error Resume Next`. Approximately: It is usually (exclusively) used on one (a few) lines and is 'ended' with an `On Error Goto 0` or with some error handling, e.g. `If Err then` which will again contain `On Error Goto 0` or some other `On Error` statement. There's a lot more to it. You should know exactly why you are using it.

**The Code**

```
Sub copyFromTableToTable()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    With wb.Worksheets("New Roster").ListObjects("NewRoster")
        Dim c As Range
        Dim dest As Range
        Dim hRow As Long
        hRow = .HeaderRowRange.Row
        For Each c In .ListColumns("OldNew").DataBodyRange
            If InStr(1, c.Value, "New") > 0 Then
                With wb.Worksheets("Current Roster").ListObjects("CurrentRoster")
                    ' This doesn't work.
                    'Set dest = .ListRows.Add
                    .ListRows.Add
                    With .DataBodyRange
                        Set dest = .Rows(.Rows.Count)
                    End With
                End With
                dest.Value = .DataBodyRange.Rows(c.Row - hRow).Value
            End If
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```